# jQuery ajax JSON errorparsed

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, node.js, parse-error

I have a JSON object that I was trying to send to a node server. I use this:

---

Generic function to make a request:

```
function makeTheRequest(method, url, data, dataType, onSuccess, onError, onComplete)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: method,//metodo|verbo con el que procesamos la peticion
        url: server + '/' + url,//url a la que hacemos la petición
        data: data,//datos del formulario
        dataType: dataType,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError,
        complete: onComplete
    });
}
```

---

Concrete function where I call the generic:

```
jQuery('#sign_log_button').on('click', function()
{

    var user = {};
    var fields = true;
    jQuery('.data').each(function(index)
    {
        if(jQuery(this).val())
            user[jQuery(this).attr('id')]=jQuery(this).val();
        else fields = false;
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    if(fields)
    {
        makeTheRequest('POST', 'users', "user=" + user , 'json', onSuccessSignLog, onErrorSignLog);
    }
    else alert("Please, check all fields.");
});
```

---

The problem I am finding is the same that many people has (I could read this problem on this forum, but no one answer is fixing me the problem... maybe I am not understanding well them).

Finally, I find a solution... and I think is great (becouse can support json and text request dataType on the server), but I would know how to do the json ajax request with jquery.

---

## My Solution

(maybe is not the best... but it is mine, and I like it ;) ) Change the line where make the calling to the generic function for this other line:

```
makeTheRequest('POST', 'users', "user=" + JSON.stringify(user) , 'text', onSuccessSignLog, onErrorSignLog);
```

And on the server side this:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res)
{
    user = req.body.user;
    if(typeof user === "string") user = JSON.parse(user);
    //MORE AND MORE
    res.send(user.user_name);   
});
```

How I said, I think it is not bad becouse the server is more flexible, but I had been a long time trying to make a json ajax request... and I want to find the solution.

PS: My english is not the best... excuse me!!

Comment: Are you trying answer your own question? If so, provide the answer as an answer, don't put it in your question.

Comment: Also, [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: I do not understand the problem.
Why do you think you are sending ' "user=" + user ' in JSON format? Setting the dataType to json does not mean you are posting the data in JSON format but means that the response you are getting back form the server is in JSON format.

Comment: " but means that the response you are getting back form the server is in JSON format" should be "but means that you expect the response you are getting back form the server is in JSON format".

Comment: Thank you very much guys... you open my eyes. I confused left with right, I thought that JSON.parse was used to build a JSON object (serialize) and the JSON.stringfy was used to convert it on a string, becouse how Ben Alman sais (thanks @FelixKling) I I did not distinguish between JSON object and javascript native objects. And thanks @Barry becouse now I know what is the meaning of dataType... 
I'm green in this area, but gradually becoming less.